# How to change content of a picture box using a context menu?

Tags: vb.net

I have been trying to work out how to change the content of a picture box using a context menu. The idea is that the user would have a choice of three images which are saved in the resources file to change the main picture on the form. Is this possible?

These are the few options that I have tried from looking around on the net:

```
    Private Sub ButtonImage1ToolStripMenuItem_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e       As System.EventArgs) Handles ButtonImage1ToolStripMenuItem.Click
    PictureBox1 = (My.Resources.button1)

End Sub
```

and

```
    Private Sub ButtonImage1ToolStripMenuItem_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e       As System.EventArgs) Handles ButtonImage1ToolStripMenuItem.Click
    PictureBox1.Image = (My.Resources.button1)

End Sub
```

and

```
    Private Sub ButtonImage1ToolStripMenuItem_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e       As System.EventArgs) Handles ButtonImage1ToolStripMenuItem.Click
    PictureBox1.Image.Replace(My.Resources.button1)

End Sub
```

None of these have actually worked. I am very new to VB.net so any direction to resources or pointers on the correct way of doing this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use the [PictureBox.Load](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.picturebox.load.aspx) method for this.